# Naive Bayes model in R on a sparse matrix

Tags: r, package

I have a very large sparse matrix (encoded using sparse.model.matrix(~. - 1, data = train), and would like to train a Naive Bayes model on it.

Is there a package in R that would allow me to do this?  I checked e1071 and klar, but both do not seem to accept a sparse matrix as input.

Is there any other packages besides glmnet that accept a sparse matrix, or is it my only choice?

Comment: you can try `sparseLDA::sda` but I'm sure there are other packages for that in  http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be no R implementation of Naive Bayes that supports sparse matrices.